# How can I slow a game down?

Tags: pc, technical-issues

I'm trying to play The Binding of Isaac on my laptop, but the game is just running too fast for me.  I can slow it down if I unplug my laptop, which I believe throttles my CPU.  I'd like to find some generic way to artificially slow a game down.

Questions similar to this have been asked before, but I don't want to have to [load up a VM](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12429/how-to-fix-dungeon-keeper-mouse-lag-a-program-to-slow-down-cpu-needed) or [pay money](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16337/how-can-i-speed-up-or-slow-down-old-3d-games) for a solution.  Is there some way to slow down or throttle my CPU slightly in order to make games like this slightly easier?

Comment: I am afraid your motivation will not matter. The answer is the same to the already existing questions that tackle the very same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix Dungeon Keeper mouse lag? A program to slow down CPU needed?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12429/how-to-fix-dungeon-keeper-mouse-lag-a-program-to-slow-down-cpu-needed)

Comment: Argh, okay.  They both seemed similar, but not the same as what I was asking.  If the consensus is they're too similar, I'll move my answer to there instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was happening when I unplugged it that effectively throttled the CPU, go to:

Control Panel -> Power Options -> Edit Plan Settings -> Change advanced power settings

Look for "Processor Power Management" and you can edit the settings from there.  [image]

It would be nice if there was a quicker/hotkey way to do this though, as I don't like to have to keep digging back into the control panel.

Comment: You can make a seperate power profile with these settings customized, and switch profiles through the power icon in your notification area.

Answer (score 1):

You guessed correctly why the CPU performance changed, so I won't comment on that any further.

Historically however, there was a similar problem with older (DOS) games running too fast, because they weren't built for modern processors.
For this reason, some utilities able to throttle the CPU emerged. You can [find some](http://www.sierrahelp.com/Utilities/SlowdownUtilities.html) with a quick Google search.
Keep in mind what the webpage says, though - this approach may not be suitable for modern games and the newest processors.