# How do I get A Gift from Krampus?

Tags: achievements, the-binding-of-isaac

Binding of Isaac has an achievement for "A Gift From Krampus". The hint says it's in Satan's room, but I don't know where that is.

Comment: Do not even consider to make this achievement if you not played this a lot. For a begginer it will take about a month and some destroyed keyboards, monitors and some furniture to achieve skill level needed for this achievement. If you buyed it now, simply forget the money. And if you got it from Humble Think about the other games about the good ones.

Comment: @NepoVim Yeah, that's what it's sounding like. I think I'm going to pass on this one.

Comment: @NepoVim I don't think it was that bad for me. I remember it taking about a couple of days and some shouting for me to get decently competent at that game.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I have to agree. While this game is no walk in the park, if you get lucky with your first few items in a playthrough, it's not bad at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amongst other factors, beating the boss without losing health increases your chance of seeing [satan's room](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Devil_Room), occasionally satan will not be there and you can instead fight [Krampus](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Krampus). He fights similar to [the fallen](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/The_Fallen).

Comment: It's worth noting that the door to the Satan room appears in the boss's room after the boss is defeated.

Answer (score 7):

The Binding of Isaac is a tricky game, and this achievement is made worse by its randomness.

### Krampus

As others have said, Krampus can be found in Satan's Room, which appears after a boss has been defeated, usually if you did well (took very little damage) on a level.  The first few levels of any Binding of Isaac game are generally not that hard.

Krampus is a boss-like enemy with two major moves.  One move fires 4 laser beams in a cross pattern.  Before he does this move, he looks like he might sneeze.  The other move fires a set of red shots in your current direction.  He winds up with this move by puffing out his cheeks.  As long as you keep moving, and stay out of the cardinal directions when the laser move is charging, you'll be fine.

### General Isaac Strategy

You'll start with a key and a bomb, in a room that explains the controls.  You can find keys, bombs, coins, hearts, and other items in the various rooms on each floor.  I always explore the entire level before attempting to fight the boss.

If you encounter an item, and aren't sure how to use it or if you want to buy it, consult [this list](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Items) on the Isaac Wikia.  Many items are tricky or not fully explained in the game.  Items that activate with <kbd>Space</kbd> need time to recharge - depending on the item, you'll have to clear a number of rooms in order to recharge it.  Try to save these for the bosses if they're particularly useful.

There will be one room with a "golden" door in it.  That room will always contain an item.  On the first level, it's unlocked, but on other levels it will be locked and you'll need a key.  Always prioritize these rooms if you can.

The only other rooms that are locked are the shops.  Don't bother unlocking the shop unless you have a good number of keys (say, 3 or 4 or more) and/or a good number of coins (ideally 5-10 or more).  Otherwise, you'll waste the key to see the shop's inventory, which you can't afford.

Bombs can be used offensively, but there's usually a hidden room on each level that's a better trade.  Finding it without certain items (like the X-Ray Specs) can be hard, but it's usually the empty space which is most surrounded by other rooms.

There are other objects and rooms you might encounter, (like the arcade, or blood machines/slot machines) but they're fairly rare in the first few levels, which is really where you want to focus for this achievement.

There's also occasionally a door that has crossed swords on it, this is the challenge room.  For the purposes of this achievement, just ignore this - it's usually got a chest with a few items in it, but you'll have to then fight waves of enemies.

After fighting the boss of a level, you'll have the option to leave the level via a trap door.  When the trap door appears, if you qualified for the Satan's Room on that level, it will open a new door in one of the walls.

### Farming Krampus

If you make it past the first couple of levels and don't encounter a Satan's Room, try starting over.  Sometimes you'll get a really powerful item early that will make everything easier.  In general though, learn the attack patterns of the enemies, and stay on the move.  You'll quickly get the hang of it.

I got this in 15 minutes in my first Devil room, but apparently the odds of that happening are abysmally low.  I don't have hard numbers on the probability of Krampus spawning, and I can't find any references of anyone who has crunched the numbers.  The community consensus seems to be that using Cain causes him to spawn more frequently.  I would suggest playing only the first few floors of the game, to minimize the headaches of playing the lower floors for far less gain than the early floors.

On the other hand, some of the optional bosses only spawn after the game has been cleared a number of times, (For instance, the [Horsemen](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Horseman) only spawn after Mom's been defeated) so if you've run the first few levels already and gotten devil rooms without seeing him, it might make sense to try clearing the game once or twice to see if that makes a difference.  For reference, I had cleared the Womb levels before, but I had not yet gotten to Sheol.

If you're having trouble avoiding damage, try slowing the game down.  I [throttle my CPU](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38268/how-can-i-slow-a-game-down) on some of the lower levels to make the game a bit easier, personally.  You'll have way more time to dodge and react to enemy fire this way.

Comment: I have to take issue with your first paragraph. I've played at least 20 hours, and reached Satan's room at least 30 times, using every character except ???, without once encountering Krampus.

Comment: @Fambida, unfortunately it appears to be random.  No one to date has calculated the odds of him spawning, although I've collated several forum threads and people at least believe they have better luck with Cain.  I'd suggest just playing the first few floors, although it wouldn't surprise me if you had to complete the game at least once before he will spawn.  I've cleared the game down to the boss of the Womb levels before, so I don't know if that's a factor or not.

Comment: While I'm disappointed that no one was able to provide more info, you definitely gave the best answer, so you get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

I found him in satan's room right after beating monstro or whatever the name is..(bought it like half an hour ago lol)
No achievement though.
Glitched?

Comment: I had the same problem. This patch will unlock all the achievements you weren't given. http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2216833

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way of telling when Krampus will spawn. However it **is** more likely with Cain as he has the Lucky Foot, which increases the chance of Devil Rooms, rare treasures, etc.

Also to fight Krampus you have to be of some skill (keep in mind he is harder than The Fallen) but if you **can** beat the Fallen easily, then you should be able to kill Krampus. The attacks of the two bosses are almost the same and he will always drop the same item. He has the same amount of health as your average Chub and he is a very unpredictable boss. You can find more information on this boss here: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Krampus