# How can I slow down Utawarerumono Mission Maps

Tags: technical-issues, utawarerumono

I have Utawarerumono English Patch on my Windows 7 64-bit Desktop PC. When I'm in the mission maps it's quite fast; one of the mechanics is that you can perform combos by clicking at the right time when you make an attack indicated by a circle.

Because the mission maps run quite fast, there is very little time to even see the circle and while holding the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key can ensure that the combo hits in the tutorial it's said it's effectiveness is reduced (obviously to deter using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> Key to auto Combo), I've also noticed that when I do, people like Touka, Kuuran and Hakuro first deal about 70 damage in their first normal attack but attacks done via combos using the Alt key only do 1 Damage making it entirely useless.

I would like to slow Utawarerumono down so that I can pull off combos for Eruru as Eruru even though she only heals I have learned that her healing can be a combo as well allowing me to heal my characters faster however just like attacking character, her combos using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key will just heal 1 HP which is just as useless.

EDIT:

This is a screenshot on the in game benchmark test

[image]

As for the specs of my PC, I can't find the paper which has them all written down and I can't remember what my graphics card is however I have an i7 64-bit Processor overclocked to 4.2 GHz and 4 GB DDR3 Ram, if it's any consolation I can play Starcraft 2 at max settings and Skyrim at max settings minus anti-aliasing for shadows

also, i know that it is more than the Battle Maps, after completing Normal last night the final scene which automatically plays while i was able to read all the text the voices were being cut off, while this could be thrown up as just the PS2's voices being incompatible with the PC release the final

> where Hakuro has been sealed and his mask is slowly falls to the ground and land in Eruru's hands

you can hear the music skipping every now and again

Comment: Is there a reason for the technical-issues tag?

Comment: @Batophobia "Technical support is for questions regarding help with technical problems such as installing or running a game" this is a technical problem with running the game as it's running way to fast at Mission Maps for one of the game's mechanics to be used

Comment: As in running faster than actual game speed (i.e. more than 60 fsp)?  From the text you provided, this sounds like a game mechanic, not a technical issue.  If you want to know how to slow a game down in general, then [this is a duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38268/42984).

Comment: @Batophobia nope it's not a game mechanic as everything is faster, the charters move at lighting speed, the numbers representing damage (ior healing in Eruru's case) are barley up long enough for you to read and maps which is supposed to be raining the rain effects you can't see (to me a while before i found out why Aruru was saying Mukuur "doesn't like the water" when there was none")

Comment: @Batophobia also the answer is for a laptop, in my question i state it's for a PC and just like in the question you supplied i don't want to use a Virtual Machine and i don't think FRAPS works with Utawarerumono cause i havn't been able to get it to work in anything but mainstream game which was meant to be released in English

Comment: @Batophobia the game also comes with a benchmark test for your computer which tells you how well it can handle the game, mine barley registers anything on the bar

Comment: A laptop is a PC, without your specs we have no way to know which you are using.  There are certainly ways to throttle the components of your machine, but some of those options will depend on what your hardware is.  The benchmark is a nice piece of information, perhaps add your results to your question.  Also, try [setting desktop colors to 16 bit](http://forums.mirrormoon.org/viewtopic.php?p=17244#p17244)

Comment: @Batophobia i've edited the question to point out that it's a Desktop PC just to make it clear, when i get home tonight i'll screenshot the benchmark test and post it and and write down the specs

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to use ***cheat engine*** (there is an option for **speed hack**) if you activate the speed hack and **leave it at 1.0** you should be able to play at normal speed, thus solving the problem. I would really not recommend trying to slow it down extra since it can really mess up the music and gameplay.

Comment: Woah, I had no idea you could use speedhack like that.